# How to run a function in a loop, pulling arguments line by line from file

Tags: python

Im writng a script that takes a url, username and password as arguments, makes a web request, and logs the resuts. I would like to use a csv file containing many sites/credentials, and loop the request for each entry and if there are any exceptions/errors I want to just skip to the next entry in the file but my script hangs after the first run of the loop

Currently Ive been just manually been passing arguments via command line flags one by one but this is not feasible as it would take ages to do manually  When I try to create a loop and pull arguments from the file, my function runs through once and then hangs indefinitely, this occurs both if there is an except or not.

```py
#currently Im using command line arguments to manually input the 
#arguments for the function below, which works fine but I want to pull 
#arguments from a list in a csv file (see comments at end for what ive #tried)


def webrequest(username,password):
 url = site
    headers = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36",
               'Accept-Encoding' : 'none'
    }
    payload = {'log': username,
               'pwd': password
               }
    session = requests.session
    r = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    if r.status_code == 404
        print "404"
        #end function, move on to next line in csv
    if r.status_code == 200
        print r.text
        # move on to next line in csv



#file = open(file, r)
#with open(file) as f:
#    for line in f:
#       args = line.split(",")
#       webrequest(args[0],args[1],args[2])
```

I expect when the function reaches the end to start over using the next line in the csv file,  but it does not.. it just hangs at the commandline

Comment: Did you debugged your code? No output/ no error?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just running a really long time? Did you try printing in the loop?

Comment: I would first test it with just two lines in the file. I would then consider introducing a delay between requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try session.post() with the timeout parameter. Details here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts

Most probably your web server isn't returning a response so you feel that your function is stuck.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the issue.  However now that I've set a timeout, once that timeout is reached theres an exception and the process exists.  How might I handle that exception properly?   like `if r.timeout: blah blah` ?

Comment: I think your first step should be to debug your server and find out why it is timing out. You can learn more about Python exception handling here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exception-handling

Comment: Its not actually my  server, Im making requests to a large list of servers, and if one times out or throws an error i just want to skip it and go to the next server in the list.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can just handle the Timeout exception and move on to the next line.